# I have two comboboxes, I want to fill one combobox by another one and the data of comboboxes are taken from SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, combobox

I have two comboboxes (CMBIDCAT) for Id of categories of product and (CMBCATNAME) for name of categories of product. When I choose the Id of category from (CMBIDCAT) combobox, I want to show the name of that chosen category in (CMBCATNAME) combobox. I use a SQL database and I use a class to access the data, stored procedure to fill comboboxes, textboxes etc., and folders to organize my work.

[I organize my work with folders and classes like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC8fO.jpg)

The following code used to fill data into my comboboxes:

```
public partial class ADD_PRODUCT_FORM : Form
{
    BL.CLS_PRODUCTS prd = new BL.CLS_PRODUCTS();

    public ADD_PRODUCT_FORM()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CMBIDCAT.DataSource = prd.GET_ID_CATEGORIES();
        CMBIDCAT.DisplayMember = "ID_CAT";
        CMBIDCAT.ValueMember = "ID_CAT";
        CMBCATNAME.DataSource = prd.GET_ID_CATEGORIES();
        CMBCATNAME.DisplayMember = "CAT_NAME";
        CMBCATNAME.ValueMember = "CAT_NAME";
    }
}
```

I hope someone can explain my problem by appropriate form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you would need two comboBoxes? Instead you better use one comboBox which shows the Id and Name like this:

```
public partial class ADD_PRODUCT_FORM : Form
{
    BL.CLS_PRODUCTS prd = new BL.CLS_PRODUCTS();

    public ADD_PRODUCT_FORM()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CMBIDCAT.DataSource = prd.GET_ID_CATEGORIES();
        CMBIDCAT.DisplayMember = "CAT_NAME";
        CMBIDCAT.ValueMember = "ID_CAT";
    }
}
```

This will show one comboBox. If you open it (or select a value) you see the Id and the corresponding name. You can access the selected value like this:

```
private void GetComboValue()
{
   var value = CMBIDCAT.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
   if (value != null)
   {
       int id = value["ID_CAT"];
       string name = value["CAT_NAME"];          
   }

   //OR if you just need Id
   int id = Convert.ToInt(CMBIDCAT.SelectedValue);
}
```

Expect that you DataSource is a DataTable.